# iOS 6 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate not getting called for navigation controllers pushed viewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

For my app `rootViewController` is `navgationController`.

I found that 
pushed controller's

`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` is not getting called.

and

`-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` get called only once.

I have checked correctly in `xcode's` project summary (or `plist`) for windows all orientation support.

I want these method to get called, as there is some uicontrol positioning code which i want to execute programmatically for orientation change.

I solved this problem by overriding (category) navigation controller's following methods

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

I checked which controller is getting pushed and accordingly called respective pushed controller's uicontrol positioning code in Navigation controller's following method

```
(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

This is working fine but i dont think this is correct way. Please help me out for better solution.

Comment: In my case (as I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610132/multiple-uiinterfaceorientations-app-with-ios-6) I wasn't able to deal with presentModalViewControllers, but the pushViewController worked fine

Answer (score 27):

You can check the following link, you need to create custom navigation to support should auto rotate

http://mobileappdevpage.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-use-should-autorotateios-6-with.html

The other way you can do this by creating category of UINaviagationController

code for .h file is

```
@interface UINavigationController (autorotation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

and code for .m file is

```
@implementation UINavigationController (autorotation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
    return YES;

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue with the navigation controller. It works fine in the case of all the pushed view controllers, but my scenario was quite different I had one viewcontroller pushed in to the navigation controller (ViewControllerParent) as the root,

```
NavController
            -- rootViewController (ViewControllerParent)
                                          --- ViewControllerChild1
                                          --- ViewControllerChild2
```

Due to some project requirement, I was keeping the ViewControllerParent as base, and then I was adding Child viewcontroller's view as subviews to the parent based on user actions. Now I had a scenario where I wanted Child1 not to rotate and Child2 to have rotation.

The problem I faced was that my [self.topViewController] in the Navigation controller class always returns me the Parent Object since I am not pushing the Childs into the nav stack. So my shouldAutorotate methods in my Childs will never be called. So I had to put a class check in the shouldAutorotate method of my parent and then return the rotation value.
I did something like this in parent class (ViewControllerParent),it is a kind of workaround but it fixed the issue

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  BOOL allowRotation = YES;

   if ([currentlyLoadedChild isKindOfClass:[Child1 class]])
   {
       allowRotation = NO;
   }
   if ([currentlyLoadedChild isKindOfClass:[Child2 class]])
   {
       allowRotation = YES;
   }
   return allowRotation;
}
```

-anoop

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the interface orientation via

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation
```

when the view controller is loaded, say, in `viewWillAppear`. There you can do your layout of subviews. Once the view is up, `shouldAutorotate` will be called whenever the device is turned.

Comment: But mind you supportedInterfaceOrientations will only be called once

Comment: No, sorry. I just tested this on a fresh project. Whenever I turn, both methods get called exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding UINavigationController is the right approach, but I'm not sure if you're checking the push controllers supportedInterfaceOrientations the correct way.

Look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669343/253008

Comment: No I'm checking the push controllers supportedInterfaceOrientations the correct way. Everything is working correctly as expected. I just want to know is there any other alternative for solution i found (overriding methods) so that pushed controllers -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations; will get called automallically whenever orientation changed. So i can skip checking which controller is pushed and calling its UIControl reposition code accordingly from overriden method. As this UIControl repositioning code is already there in controllers orientation methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037274/shouldautorotate-not-working-with-navigation-controllar-swift-2?answertab=active#tab-top)
its a great approauch rather than applying ShouldAutoRotate