# shouldAutorotate not working with navigation controllar swift 2

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift2, ios9, xcode7, screen-orientation

my app uses several libraryies. Bassically [KYDrawerController](https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController). I want my App to use only potraite Orientation but for one ViewControllar i need both landscape and Potrait.

I have search about allmost every solution on the internet. every solution was to subclass the NavigationControllar and Override ShouldAutoRotate method. but non of them worked for me.

and [here is the closer View of the entire StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGweO.png)

the gray color View is the KYDrawerControllar view which is an libry uses to work as NavigationDrawer like Android.

I have created a custom Class for Navigation Controllar and subclass it to the requierd ViewControllar's Navigation Controllar.

here is the Code

```
class SettingsNavigation: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   NSLog("visibleControllar", self.visibleViewController!.debugDescription)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    //return self.visibleViewController!.shouldAutorotate()
    return false
}
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}



/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

here is the ViewControllar

```
class Settings: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var profileName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var profileRegistrationType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var logOutButton: FUIButton!
@IBOutlet var subscriptionType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var subscriptionRegistrationType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var upgradeSubscriptionButton: FUIButton!



override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
   /* if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
            return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }*/

    return false

}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
} }
```

and i am using StoryBoard segues to present ViewControllars.

please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is my way:

1. in your `appdelegae.swift`:

   ```
   var shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
   func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
       if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == true){
           return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
       }
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
   }
   ```
2. in your entry view which enter the all orientation view (change to support all orientation, here I use a button as an example):

   ```
   @IBAction func next(sender: UIButton) {
       let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
       appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = true
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)
   }
   ```
3. in your entry view which enter the all orientation view (change the orientation to support only Portrait):

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
       appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
   }
   ```
4. finally, you may find this works on all iPhone device and iPad ipad2 except iPad air iPad pro; you should check the "requires full screen" in your project general info to ensure you all orientation view can enter landscape.

Comment: Thank You , i will try this and let you know :)

Comment: @GishanthaJayasooriya it works. but for ipad air and pro you need check the require full screen

Comment: @Xingou Thanks. Saved my time